# Activation record trace by a recursion method

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Because of that to learn very-well logic of behind recursive idea, I'm practising while studying data structures by using debugger. The problem may seem easy but it just makes a sensation. The method finds maximum element in a binary search tree. - As a rule, binary search tree([click here](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/adalal/teaching/s05/127/notes/BinarySearchTree.java) for full implementation) is a tree in which left child has less elements than root element and right child has higher elements than root element. - Until finding it, the method goes into new activation frame and push it onto atop of the stack. Having been found, they are popped off in-reversed order(LIFO). My question is that why does the method return second statement(`return findMax(node.right)`)? If the debugger shows activation frames being popped off, why does it just show the one time? I hope images aid to comprehend my question more as well.

[image]

```
/* bST.add(1),bST.add(3),bST.add(7),bST.add(6),bST.add(4),
   bST.add(13),bST.add(14),bST.add(10),bST.add(8); */

/**
 * Find max element in the BST
 * @param node local node being given
 * @return max element
 */
public E findMax(Node<E> node) {
        if (node.right == null)
            return node.data;
        return findMax(node.right);
}
```

[image]

Comment: last screenshot `node` is 13 where it was 14 before. You need to check the call stack. you are most likely not in the same method call

Comment: [(((Watch))) out please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp9xx.gif)  @Flikk

Comment: see your stack trace. You are just going backwards after `node.right` is null. Not sure why the debugger jumps over the rest of the stack trace though. Not working with IntelliJ maybe the "force step into" would help you. or maybe the "step out" when you go backwards

Answer (score 0):

The code works down the right side of the tree until it hits the largest element: the one with no right child.  Then it returns the data value of that node -- *to the instance that called it*.  That was the instance called from node 13.

The particular statement **return node.data** is the base case for this recursion.  The second one, **return findMax(node.right)**, is the recursion case.  By the time you reach the value **14**, you have four of these **returns** stacked up, waiting for results.

The one from node 13 will then pass the value **14** back to the call from node 7, continuing down the stack until the call from node 1 returns the value **14** to whatever called **findMax** in the first place.

I don't know why your debugger shows evidence of only the first activation "pop".  I don't know what settings you're using.  If you're single-stepping, or have a breakpoint set at the *return* (as well as the **findMax** call), you should see both ends of that: going down another level, and then coming back up in LIFO order.

Does that clear up anything for you?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. However, I'm aware and agree with you up to last paragraph wondered. You can see the "step into" forwarding and others from [the link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp9xx.gif) Debugging properties are standart IntelliJ IDE's. En passant, as well as I think it's related to IDE so, aids of experienced people like you help me to be sure I think right.

Comment: Yes.  That's "step into", but the return from that takes a big leap when it's stepping out.  I recall that from when I was using IntelliJ.  I think we stopped the big leap by setting a breakpoint in the assembly code.